# How can I set a series to be a specific color in Apps Script (for a scatter plot in Google Sheets)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently writing a program on Google's Apps Script. I am trying to modify my scatter plot. I would like the series B28:B60 to come up as red dots and the series C28:C60 to come up as green dots. How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
function createScatterPlot(newSheet) {
  Logger.log("--- createScatterPlot ---");
  var chartBuilder = newSheet.newChart()
  .asScatterChart()
  .setXAxisTitle('Student')
  .setYAxisTitle('Time')
  .addRange(newSheet.getRange('A28:A60'))
  .addRange(newSheet.getRange('B28:O60'))
  .setPosition(2,1,0,0)
  .setOption('width', 960)
  .setOption('height', 480)
  .build();
  newSheet.insertChart(chartBuilder);
}
```

Okay, I tried adjusting it according to Tanaike. It does change the plot points to green/red, but I am still having some issues with it updating correctly with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `I would like the series B28:B60 to come up as red dots and the series C28:C60 to come up as green dots.`, in this case, how about using `setColors` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function createScatterPlot(newSheet) {
  var range2 = newSheet.getRange('B28:O60');
  var chartBuilder = newSheet.newChart()
    .asScatterChart()
    .setXAxisTitle('Student')
    .setYAxisTitle('Time')
    .addRange(newSheet.getRange('A28:A60'))
    .addRange(range2)
    .setPosition(2, 1, 0, 0)
    .setOption('width', 960)
    .setOption('height', 480)
    .setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")])
    .build();
  newSheet.insertChart(chartBuilder);
}
```

- By this modification, `newSheet.getRange('A28:A60')` and `newSheet.getRange('B28:O60')` are set as "red" and "green", respectively.

#### Reference:

- [setColors(cssValues)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-scatter-chart-builder#setcolorscssvalues)

### Added:

From your provided Spreasheet, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function createScatterPlot2(newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1")) {
  var range1 = newSheet.getRange('A28:B60');
  var range2 = newSheet.getRange('C28:O60');
  var chartBuilder = newSheet.newChart()
    .asScatterChart()
    .setXAxisTitle('Student')
    .setYAxisTitle('Time')
    .addRange(range1)
    .addRange(range2)
    .setPosition(2, 1, 0, 0)
    .setOption('width', 960)
    .setOption('height', 480)
    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
    .setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")])
    .build();
  newSheet.insertChart(chartBuilder);
}
```

When this script is run with your provided Spreadsheet, the following chart is created.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this but it didn't work. Could it be because setColors is for line graphs (and not for scatter plots). It might also be because the data on the arrays are not populated at the beginning of the program. It comes in periodically after the scatter plot is created. I'm a total beginner at this so I have no idea. I've also read that Apps Script might not even allow the changing of colors of the points but I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for replying. About `I tried this but it didn't work. Could it be because setColors is for line graphs (and not for scatter plots).`, although I'm not sure about the detail of it, I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, I think that it is required to know your situation. Because when I tested my modified script using a simple Spreadsheet, the script works. I have to apologize for this. So, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @ScythaScytha By the way, in your reply, you say `and not for scatter plots`. But, your script uses `.asScatterChart()`. I'm confusing your situation. I apologize for this. In this case, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current situation? And, can I ask you about the detail of your actually expected result?

Comment: Of course. Here's a copied set of example data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HOx8ID4EbfBuyszkv5m1QKennzzwytqhhrDq5Y3GREk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: my goal is to change the 'departure' times to red, and the 'arrival' times to green. But the dots seem to be stuck in their standard color.

Comment: @ScythaScytha From your provided Spreadsheet, I added one more script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, please tell me. I would like to modify it. If you want to set the color of "C28:C60" as "green", please modify `var range2 = newSheet.getRange('C28:O60');` to `var range2 = newSheet.getRange('C28:C60');`.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks so much for helping. I updated my post with the new function

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for replying. When I tested your updated script using your provided Spreadsheet, I can confirm that a chart of my showing image can be created. This is not your added image. I apologize for this. So, I'm worried that you might use a different Spreadsheet from your provided Spreadsheet. How about this? My proposed script is for your provided Spreadsheet because I have no other information. So, please test my script using your provided Spreadsheet. If I misunderstood your actual situation, I apologize.

Comment: @ScythaScytha By the way, in your provided Spreadsheet, I noticed that a chart (with the default color) has already been added. In this case, when the script is run, a new chart might be put under the current chart. I'm worried about it. So, when you test my script, please delete all charts from the sheet and test it again.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, the charts were not being populated on top of each other. I suspect the issue might be somewhere else in the code. I updated my post with the rest of the functions in the code. Could you please look it over and see what mistake I'm making?

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that you had updated your question. In this case, I think that your updated question is different from your initial question. I would like to recommend to resolve your questions in order. So, please back your updated question to your initial question. And, please test my proposed script using your provided Spreadsheet and confirm whether the provided script works. When your question was resolved and you have a new question, please post it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @ScythaScytha By the way, in your new script, if you run the function `addNewSheetForToday()`, I think that the chart cannot be correctly created because `newSheet` has no values for creating a chart. Please be careful about this. But, I cannot know the specification of your new script because I have no information about your actual situation. I deeply apologize for this situation. But, this is a different question. So, I would like to recommend resolving your questions in order. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to all of this. Yes I did run the function you posted separately and it did successfully change the colors to red/green. It just doesn't work when I use it in my code.

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for replying. From `Yes I did run the function you posted separately and it did successfully change the colors to red/green. It just doesn't work when I use it in my code.`, I understood that my script resolved your initial question. In this case, please accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer About your added script, I have already proposed a modification point in my reply. If you want a modified script, I would like to continue supporting you. So, please post it as a new question. By this, it will help users think of a solution.

Comment: Alright I accepted the original answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it.

Comment: I updated my original post. I'm going to try to implement your script into my code for a while and if I still can't get it, I'll make another post haha. Thank you again for all the help!!!!! :)

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for your response, again. About your whole script, although  I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand it, as a simple modification, how about modifying from `var newSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(formattedDate)` to `var newSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1").copyTo(spreadsheet).setName(formattedDate)` in `addNewSheetForToday()` function if you are using your provided Spreadsheet. By this, the values for the chart are also copied.

Comment: @ScythaScytha But, I'm not sure about your actual situation. So, when this was not the direct solution to your new issue, I apologize. At that time, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question.

Comment: @ScythaScytha By the way, in your whole script, it seems that Web Apps is used. If you test the Web Apps, please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps and test it. Please be careful about this.

Comment: No the spreadsheet I sent you was just a copy of the spreadsheet I'm using. The data, sheets, and scatter plot all work perfectly fine. It's just changing the color that I can't seem to get. Any way. I will try playing around with it, using your suggested solution, and maybe figure something out.

Comment: Yeah it does use the Web Apps Script. I tested yours and it worked. I just am having trouble integrating it with the rest of the code.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I posted a new question about this. Maybe you could still help me lol